# Put objects in alphabetical order by data attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to group my list objects into an alphabetical order and add a title of them.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="projectLists">
  <ul data-year="france">
    <li>items france</li>   
</ul>
<ul data-year="austria">
    <li>items austria</li>   
</ul>
<ul data-year="united kingdom">
    <li>items united kingdom</li>   
</ul>
<ul data-year="USA">
    <li>items USA</li>   
</ul>
<ul data-year="france">
    <li>items france</li>   
</ul>
<ul data-year="united kingdom">
    <li>items united kingdom</li>   
</ul>
<ul data-year="austria">
    <li>items austria</li>   
</ul>
<ul data-year="USA">
    <li>items USA</li>   
</ul>
```

The jQuery code I am using does some trick:

```
var $ul = $('.projectLists > ul');
years = {};

$ul.each(function(){
 years[$(this).data('year')] = '';
});

for (year in years) {
 $ul.filter('[data-year='+ year +']').wrapAll('<div class="year"></div');
 }

 var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('ul').sort(function(a, b) {
        return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('year').toLowerCase(),    $(b).data('year').toLowerCase());
    });

 var container = $(".projectLists");
 container.detach().empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
 $('body').append(container);
```

I am trying to achieve this view:

Austria
 - items Austria
 - items Austria

France
 - items France
 - items France

United Kingdom
 - items United Kingdom
 - items United Kingdom
USA
 - items USA
 - items USA

I do really appreciate your help. The working JSfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/1sa3mvpz/

Comment: Please post the expected _HTML output_.

Comment: Please see my amended JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/1sa3mvpz/1/

Also there is how I want to see it: http://jsfiddle.net/2uhdd18o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet generates the expected output:

```
var years = {}, $plist = $('.projectLists');

$plist.children('div').sort(function (a, b) {
    a = $(a).data('year');
    b = $(b).data('year');
    years[a] = null;
    years[b] = null;
    return String.prototype.localeCompare.call(a.toLowerCase(), b.toLowerCase());
}).appendTo($plist);

$.each(years, function (year) {
    $plist.children('[data-year="' + year + '"]').first().before($('<h5>', {
        text: year.replace(/\b(\w)/g, function (a) {
            return a.toUpperCase()
        })
    }));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a8rr1zp7/